# Unknown column 'xxx' in 'where clause'

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a search into my site where the search term is stored in a database.

Here is my code

```
<?php
$search = $_GET["q"];
if ($search <= "") {
 }
else {
  $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "cl49-XXX", "XXX");
  if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: line 513 ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("cl49-XXX", $con) or die("Unable to select database"); 

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM registrations WHERE 'rname' LIKE '%$search%'") or die('Error: Line 519 (' . mysql_error() . ')');

$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);   
 if ($num_rows=="0"){
  echo"<h4>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;No Results Found for <b>$search</b>. Please try a different search</h3>";
  }

  else { 
echo "<h3>$num_rows results found for <b> $search</b></h3><br /><br />";   
   }
```

If I search the name "donna" (this name is in the DB) I get the error

> Unknown column 'donna' in 'where clause'

Comment: do not use quote in table name and table attribute name

Comment: backtick (`) is not the same as inverted comma (')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As all community say: don't use **mysql_** functions, try mysqli or PDO, please. 
Advice: escape the input, prevent injections, etc.

Do: `$search = mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET["q"] );`

And change this line

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM registrations WHERE `rname` LIKE '%". $search ."%'") or die('Error: Line 519 (' . mysql_error() . ')');
```

**Edit (script improvements).** 
mysql_num_rows returns an integer value, so, why you're comparing it with string ?

```
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);   
 if (!$num_rows){
```

Or `if ($num_rows == 0)`
...

Comment: Kay, tell me what is the generated SQL.
Use ``$result = mysql_query($sql = "SELECT * FROM registrations WHERE `rname` LIKE '%". $search ."%'") or die('Error: Line 519 (' . mysql_error() . ')'); echo $sql;``

Comment: Seriously ? at top: `ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Yep... `Unknown column 'donna' in 'where clause'`

Comment: You can post the full code (currently code) at pastebin or gist ?

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM registrations WHERE 'rname' LIKE '%$search%'")
```

to

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `registrations` WHERE `rname` LIKE '%".$search."%'")
```

Comment: Sorry I have fixed the query, could you now try and see ?

Comment: Unknown column 'donna' in 'where clause'

Comment: can you run the query directly in mysql and see what you get 

SELECT * FROM `registrations` WHERE `rname` LIKE '%donna%' ;

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the column name in you table is `rname`:

```
WHERE 'rname' LIKE
```

Should be

```
WHERE rname LIKE
```

Comment: Actually, it should be `\`rname\``.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Really not necessary :)

Comment: It may not be necessary in this particular case but it's a bloomin' good practice! Especially when you're teaching, which you are.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between ` and '. You have used ' in this post for both the column name rname and '%$search%'. I guess you actually used `%$search%` in your code.

Change your code as below.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM registrations WHERE `rname` LIKE '%$search%'") or die('Error: Line 519 (' . mysql_error() . ')');
```